# How to save output from a command that creates a second popup window and immediately exits

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, batch

I am trying to run `winsat disk` from within `cmd.exe` and capture the output provided by the window that is popping up. 
Unfortunately, creating a bat file with following content:

```
start cmd.exe /k "winsat disk"
```

just prevents `cmd.exe` from closing, instead of preventing the `winsat` window from closing.

How can I save the output of this window that is popping up or prevent it from closing?

Comment: `Winsat diskformal -xml c:\winsat_diskformal.xml`

Comment: Thanks. But what if a command does not have an option to generate .xml at a user-defined directory?

Comment: Run `Winsat diskformal` and then look for XML report in a storage folder `%Windir%\Performance\WinSAT\DataStore`

Comment: Yes, I understand, but what if that would be command XYZ that would just work in the same way ie. popping up a new window which immediately closes?

Comment: The application writes results only after all tests finished. And I do not believe that 2 parallel tests can give different results so it's not interesting what copy of winsat process has generated a report...

Answer (score 1):

```
start cmd.exe /k "winsat disk > c:\temp\out.txt"
```

Comment: Can you expand on what this command is meant to do? Please see [answer] or take our [tour].